# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS cannot get IP address when directly connected to the internet

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, hyper-v

I've been playing around with Windows Hyper-V Server 2019 and basically trying to create my own cloud.

The weird thing is that I'm unable to get Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to connect to the internet directly.

It simply doesn't want to get an IP address from the modem if I set the network connection to VLAN tag id 2 (the VLAN that is directly connected to my modem) in the Hyper-V settings, neither when I set a VLAN tag 2 during the setup:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS connected to WAN]
[image: Simplified structure of my network]

However, if I set in the Hyper-V manager to connect directly to the LAN, it has no issue getting an IP address:

```
nick@ubuntu-1:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:00:04:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.171/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 43149sec preferred_lft 43149sec
    inet6 2a02:1811:2501:9c10::669/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 83890sec preferred_lft 11890sec
    inet6 fdd9:90ff:c1b6:10::669/128 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe00:40a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:74:f6:b4:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether be:57:d4:f0:61:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.86.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bc57:d4ff:fef0:61f5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tested it as well with Debian 9 & 10 and they don't seem to have those problems:

```
nick@Debian-1:~$ ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:00:04:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 94.224.239.246/20 brd 94.224.239.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 5459sec preferred_lft 5459sec
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe00:402/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Does your wan connection have a dhcp service running?

Comment: @PasiSuominen as far as I know my openwrt router & debian clients get their ip address through dhcp by looking their interface configs: 

`config interface 'wan'
        option ifname 'eth0.2'
        option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'wan6'
        option ifname 'eth0.2'
        option proto 'dhcpv6'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with my router/modem, I performed a full reset on both of them and that seemed to fix the issue. Pretty weird that all my other VM's still got their external ip's without any issue though.